# Swift SpriteKit: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS on addChild? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a game that when you die, you click and the game should restart itself, but whenever I click to restart it gives me this(see above) error. Thanks in advance(:

Here is my code:

```
class MCTFruitGen: SKSpriteNode {
    var generationTimer: NSTimer!
    var fruits = [MCTFruit]()
    var fruitTracker = [MCTFruit]()

    func startGeneratingFruitEvery(seconds: NSTimeInterval) {
        generationTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(seconds, target: self, selector: "generateFruit", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func stopGenerating() {
        generationTimer?.invalidate()
    }

    func generateFruit() {
        var scale: CGFloat
        let rand = arc4random_uniform(2)
        if rand == 0 {
            scale = -1.0
        } else {
            scale = 1.0
        }

        let strawberry = MCTFruit()
        strawberry.position.x = size.width/2 + strawberry.size.width/2
        strawberry.position.y = scale * (NMCGroundHeight/160 + strawberry.size.height)

        self.fruits.append(strawberry)
        fruitTracker.append(fruits)
        addChild(strawberry) // line that gives me the error
    }

    func stopFruit() {
        stopGenerating()
        for fruit in fruits {
            fruit.stopFruitMoving()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the part of the code where you register the click and whatever calls you are making there?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SKAction` instead of `NSTimer` for generating the fruit or any timing events in SpriteKit. For example

```
class MCTFruitGen: SKSpriteNode {
    var fruits = [MCTFruit]()
    var fruitTracker = [MCTFruit]()

    func startGeneratingFruitEvery(seconds: NSTimeInterval) {

        let callGenerateAction = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in
            self.generateFruit()
        }

        let waitOneSecond = SKAction.waitForDuration(seconds)

        let sequenceAction = SKAction.sequence([callGenerateAction, waitOneSecond])

        let fruitGeneratorAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequenceAction)

        self.runAction(fruitGeneratorAction, withKey: "fruitGenerator")
    }

    func stopGenerating() {
        self.removeActionForKey("fruitGenerator");
    }

    func generateFruit() {
        // Your Code
    }

    func stopFruit() {
        stopGenerating()
        // Your Code
    }
}
```

Comment: It took away my error, but when I tap to restart the game still stays static.

Comment: what do u mean by still stays static?

Comment: Like nothing in it moves. My sprite is moving like it should, but the ground won't move  and my obstacles won't generate.

Comment: maybe something is wrong with the way you are restarting the game. You should ask a new question showing only the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Also my "Start!" label won't go away.